# Email notifications using laravel

Tags: laravel, email, notifications

I have a notification and mail class and i would like to send email notifications to several random users when they click a button. Any ideas on how to help out with the code. Below are the 2 classes. Not sure if anything else is needed. I already set up a users table. I also configured my .env file with the credentials from my mailtrap account but not sure how to proceed. -Thanks

Notification Class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class ProvideAnswer extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('Thank you for answering the question.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Mail class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ThankYou extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('view.name');
    }
}
```

Question Form:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    {{ Breadcrumbs::render('home') }}


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Question</div>

                    <div class="card-body">

                        {{$question->body}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary float-right"
                           href="{{ route('question.edit',['id'=> $question->id])}}">
                            Edit Question
                        </a>

                        {{ Form::open(['method'  => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['question.destroy', $question->id]])}}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger float-right mr-2" value="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Delete
                        </button>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header"><a class="btn btn-primary float-left"
                                                href="{{ route('answers.create', ['question_id'=> $question->id])}}">
                            Answer Question
                        </a></div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        @forelse($question->answers as $answer)
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">{{$answer->body}}</div>
                                <div class="card-footer">

                                    <a class="btn btn-primary float-right"
                                       href="{{ route('answers.show', ['question_id'=> $question->id,'answer_id' => $answer->id]) }}">
                                        View
                                    </a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @empty
                            <div class="card">

                                <div class="card-body"> No Answers</div>
                            </div>
                        @endforelse


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
@endsection
```

AnswerController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Answer;
use App\Question;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AnswerController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create($question)
    {
        $answer = new Answer;
        $edit = FALSE;
        return view('answerForm', ['answer' => $answer,'edit' => $edit, 'question' =>$question  ]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, $question)
    {

        $input = $request->validate([
            'body' => 'required|min:5',
        ], [

            'body.required' => 'Body is required',
            'body.min' => 'Body must be at least 5 characters',

        ]);
        $input = request()->all();
        $question = Question::find($question);
        $Answer = new Answer($input);
        $Answer->user()->associate(Auth::user());
        $Answer->question()->associate($question);
        $Answer->save();

        return redirect()->route('question.show',['question_id' => $question->id])->with('message', 'Saved');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($question,  $answer)
    {
        $answer = Answer::find($answer);

        return view('answer')->with(['answer' => $answer, 'question' => $question]);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($question,  $answer)
    {
        $answer = Answer::find($answer);
        $edit = TRUE;
        return view('answerForm', ['answer' => $answer, 'edit' => $edit, 'question'=>$question ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $question, $answer)
    {
        $input = $request->validate([
            'body' => 'required|min:5',
        ], [

            'body.required' => 'Body is required',
            'body.min' => 'Body must be at least 5 characters',

        ]);

        $answer = Answer::find($answer);
        $answer->body = $request->body;
        $answer->save();

        return redirect()->route('answers.show',['question_id' => $question, 'answer_id' => $answer])->with('message', 'Updated');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($question, $answer)
    {
        $answer = Answer::find($answer);

        $answer->delete();
        return redirect()->route('questions.show',['question_id' => $question])->with('message', 'Delete');

    }
```

Mail.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can either send a `Notification` using the `ProvideAnswer` class and it would use the Laravel default email template, or you send a `Mailable` class via your the `ThankYou` class. For this you would need to build a new email template which is registered as a view in `ThankYou->build()`, currently called `view.name`. These are two separate ways to send email with Laravel.

If the default Laravel email template works for you, which I think it does, all you need to do is add the following code at the point you want to send the email:

```
$user->notify(new ProvideAnswer());
```

This assumes your User class is `Notifiable`, which it will be by default if you use Laravel's built in Auth classes. Remember to add `use path\to\ProvideAnswer;` at the top of the class that you call the notify method in.

If you want to use your own email template then you need to build a Blade template for it, point the `ThankYou build()` function at it and then call the following when you want to send the email

```
Mail::to($EMAILADDRESS)->send(new ThankYou);
```

Again make sure to alias the Mail class with the `use` statement in any class you want to send mail from.

**PS:** In general, the `Notification` approach is just for pinging alerts, and you can choose whether that's via email, SMS, etc. The `Mailable` approach is for mailing important documents, e.g. invoices, that you may want to also render as a webpage.

**PPS:** If you're not using the Laravel Auth framework for your user class, you will need to make your user notifiable to use the `ProvideAnswer` class, or use a standalone `Notification::route(...` The instructions are here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait

Comment: Greetings, thanks for the advice. Is it ok to remove the ThankYou mail class since I will use default laravel email? Also, I want to add the code at the point when user answers a question in this template so is there a specific place to insert?

Comment: I provided the template above

Comment: I also provided my AnswerController

Comment: Yes remove the `ThankYou` class. Is the question being processed via a form and a controller? That's where you would add the call to `notify()`. If your user is not logged in and/or you are not using Laravel Auth then you may want to use this method instead:

`Notification::route('mail', 'EMAILADDRESS')
            ->notify(new ProvideAnswer);`

Again this would be in the controller where you process the answer to the question.

Comment: After `Answer->save()` in your `AnswerController` add `Auth::user()->notify(new ProvideAnswer());`. Do this in the `store` method if you want it to be when the answer is first provided and in the `update` method if you also want it to be after any subsequent edits.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the user has an `email` property set, i.e. if `Auth::user()->email` returns a valid email address for the user.

Comment: I got this error msg Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "

Comment: Also, all of my users are fake. I used faker. Should I register myself in order to get email?

Comment: You can use fake email addresses with mailtrap as long as they are of valid format. But it looks like your mailtrap settings in  `.env` are wrong. Double check them.

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=7xxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=1xxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Comment: Here's my .env file

Comment: For my username and password, I entered the info from my mailtrap account. Is there somehting else I need to look at in the .env file?

Comment: I suspect you have an old / different mail_host and mail_port set in config/mail.php. Amend those, and then run `php artisan config:cache` to be sure.

Comment: See mail.php file i posted above. It's the default that i haven't touched

Comment: `'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),` change smtp.mailgun.org to smtp.mailtrap.io and `'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587)` change to port 2525.